Attaching a finite number of cells to finite CW-complex yields a finite CW-complex
As we can see, CW-complex is built from attaching cells in the order of their dimension.
I would like to confirm that, is it true that attaching finite number of cells to a finite CW-complex yields a finite CW-complex? I ask this because in one paper of Wolfgang Lück, it seems like he use this fact.
By the way, I also wish to know are there any references mentioned such these relations between gluing cells in the order of their dimension and without order?

That depends on what exactly you mean by "attaching cells to cw complex".

If you are not careful about the attaching maps, the resulting space will not be homeomorphic to a CW complex. (Attach 2-cell to the 2-dimensional sphere along, say, a map from the circle onto the Sierpinsky carpet.) However, it is always homotopy-equivalent to a finite CW complex (this is a consequence of the cellular approximation theorem).

@MoisheKohan Thank you so much, your description is really clear and helpful! (especially the cellular approximation theorem) May I ask the inverse question? If attaching cells to finite CW-complex yields a finite CW-complex, could this map always be represented by attaching a finite number of cells? In another word, a relative cell complex between finite CW-complexes must be a finite relative cell complex?

@MoisheKohan The relative cell complex which I mean, is gluing cells without dimensional oder, like what we did for relative I-cell complex in cofibrantly generated model category.

I did not really understand your question ("could this map be represented" is unclear). You should revise your post instead of asking in comments. Maybe what you mean to ask is: If the underlying space $|X|$ of a relative cell complex $X$ is homeomorphic to the total space of a finite cell complex, is it true that there is a finite relative subcomplex $Y\subset X$ such that $|Y|=|X|$? (Personally, I prefer to distinguish between a complex and its underlying space, especially in the questions like yours.)
